# tomcat reload first login takes lot of time

Tags: windows, tomcat

Whenever I restart tomcat and reload my site, It takes a lot of time. Is there a way around? like not having to restart tomcat. I have already tried [`reloadable="true"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371724/having-to-restart-tomcat-whenever-you-make-a-change) but that doesn't help.

Comment: Can you elaborate "but that doesn't help" more ?

Comment: Did you try to trace or use a profiler to find out what code exactly is taking so much time to execute ?

Comment: Take several thread dumps during startup to find out what is taking your webapp so long. An otherwise unconfigured Tomcat stock Tomcat 7.0.28 takes about 2.5sec to come up on moderately modern hardware (2GHz CPU, multi-processor doesn't matter since starting up with no webapps is single-threaded), so this is definitely your webapp's problem.