# hot deploy changes done to beans in application context dont show up

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, applicationcontext

In the process of extending functionality of my application, I added injected few additional bean references into my existing bean definitions in applicationContext. I included their getters and setters in my java class. Class A refers to beans B and C newly now and in class A, I added getters and setter for B and C and used these getters in methods inside Class A.
Beans B and C are nothing more than Maps and there is a class D in which I put values into these beans.
Now, instead of generating a whole war file again in the production machine, I generated the war in my local copy. From this war I picked up classes A and D and replaced the ones on production machine with these new classes. Also, I replaced the applicationContext.xml.
After restarting tomcat on the production machine, I get a NPE in Class A which is because of the getter of bean B. My values dont seem to be injected in the bean.

What can I do to solve this? I do not want to redeploy the whole war on my production machine.

Comment: Most ide's support hot deploy if you set them correctly :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998737/integrating-tomcat-and-eclipse-as-a-hot-deploy-environment

Comment: NimChimpsky, I want my changes to reflect on a production machine. Not my local copy.

Comment: is their a reason you can't just deploy the new war file ?

Comment: I have changes in other files that I dont want to go into the production machine yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you restart tomcat it will unpack any war file that is present, overwriting any changes you have done *manually*.  If I understand correctly you are attempting to copy class files into your exploded war.  Not a particularly good idea.

You don't have to gerenate a war file on the same machine it is deployed on (in fact that would be unusual). You may app specific settings to be aware of.

Comment: NimChimpsky, I am not generating war file on the same machine. I am generating war file on one machine and trying to copy specific files onto another.

Comment: only include the changes you want released, use a source control system (git,mercurial, subversion)