# Eclipse + JSP (Tomcat) - how to run / debug servlet efficiently from IDE?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrating tomcat and eclipse as a hot-deploy environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998737/integrating-tomcat-and-eclipse-as-a-hot-deploy-environment)

I try to do a web project using Tomcat in Eclipse.

In the IDE, I can use Run on a JSP file, in which case it starts server and runs web browser with url set to the JSP file. So far good, because JSP file is really deployed to server.

However, my JSP file uses some JAVA files. When I edit the JAVA file, and use Run in Eclipse, it opens web url that contains path to the JAVA file, which is actually invalid URL, because JAVA files get compiled to classes, and actually are not present on web in their original form.

Question: how do I configure Eclipse Run/Debug command to open fixed URL (e.g. my start page) when developing a web project and trying to run or debug something (other than jsp file).

I try to gain productivity, which would allow me to edit some (java) file, and debug it, without need to switch to other file in the IDE in order to begin debugging.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I need to add that my java file is not a real servlet (not inheriting HttpServlet), but piece of Java used in JSP tags.

Anyway, question remains and may be extended: is it possible to define entry point for running web app from Eclipse, and possibly specify URL get/post parameters (when using Run/Debug command from Eclipse)?

Comment: How did you make this web project?

Comment: Eclipse: New dynamic web project.

Comment: Open a web browser, enter the URL of your start page in the address bar, type Enter, then add a bookmark to this page in the "personal bar" of your browser (this is at least how it's called in Firefox). Whenever you want to reload the home page, click on this bookmark.

Comment: Maybe it works, but is far from optimal. I'm looking for way to edit java source, hit a debug key, and run Firefox directly from Eclipse. Switching windows and clicking by mouse kills productivity.

Comment: switching windows doesn't kill productivity, in fact my ide (intellij) uses the window losing focus as the debug key. If you must use eclipse this might help http://stackoverflow.com/q/998737/106261