# How to prevent restart my web application( not only restart the tomcat server)?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I know I can prevent the server restart, when I publish my app to Tomcat.

But, each time, I have to restart my application. and This is also take a long time,

Can I prevent restart my application, just like PHP does?

ps:

after run tomcat in debug mode, now, I can modify java file without a redeploy! but it doesn't apply to jsp pages! How can I submit jsp without the "publish"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998737/integrating-tomcat-and-eclipse-as-a-hot-deploy-environment

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat makes the very reasonable assumption that you may have done something quite drastic since the last deploy. You can fiddle with minor JSP changes in the work directory, but eventually you will need to redeploy.

Comment: after run tomcat in debug mode, now, I can modify java file without a redeploy! but it doesn't apply to jsp pages! How can I submit jsp without the "publish"?

Comment: Try redeploying while Tomcat is running. I have had mixed results. Applications based on Spring MVC seem to not want to redeploy, but ordinary JSP servlet apps normally hot-deploy reliably.