# Hot deployment issue with java class in MyEclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using **myeclipse** with tomcat installation When I have change my java class in web project(servlet class or tag class) it will not  reflect in my eclipse unless and until I redeploy  project  in tomcat. even if  I select auto publish of resources in tomcat, its not reflected.When I changed my jsp files its work fine and reflect the changes.so is there any special way to set hot deployment in **myeclipse** as this was works normally in **eclipse**.?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/998737/274350

Comment: @RichardNeish I have problem with myeclipse not eclipse, in eclipse its works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't mention the release of MyEclipse that you're using but, in all releases, you need to start Tomcat in debug mode for this to work. Also, note that some class changes cannot be hot swapped (e.g. if you change a method signature).