# How to update content of webapp in maven Project instantly?

Tags: java, maven, servlets, web-applications

I have a Maven WebApp project in which i am continuously changing my servlet class, Whenever i change my servlet class i to have re-run the project by clean package and tomcat:run, if i don't re-run, it doesn't show changes on webapp what i change in servlet class, Is there any fast method to update my project instead of re-run the project because it takes a lot of time to re-run.

I am using eclipse ide for running my project, so please give me solution based on eclipse.

Suppose that's my servlet classs

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login_Bridge
 */
@WebServlet("/abc")
public class abc extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public abc() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hello1");

    }

}
```

Suppose i add another System.out.println("Hello2") in my get method, and when i refresh my page on browser it doesnot show any changes but when i re-run the project by (clean package) then (tomcat:run), then it shows changes on browser so my question is, Is there any other method to do this in a fast way so that i can see changes in fast way.

Comment: @jogo i have updated my question!

Comment: any changes made inside the WEB-INF folder will probably endup redeploying the application itself

Comment: but my servlet class doesn't inside WEB-INF folder

Comment: If I understood correctly what are you trying to achieve, then [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) is what you should look at.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the hot Deploy feature in eclipse [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998737/integrating-tomcat-and-eclipse-as-a-hot-deploy-environment%7D). But if you are trying to debug your application I'd suggest you to use unit testing instead.

It's much more convenient than hot deployment.

example:

```
@Mock
private HttpServletRequest request;
@Mock       
private HttpServletResponse response;

private YourServletClass sut;

@Before
public void initTest(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    //Init your mocks as yuou wish
    when(request.getParameter("parameter1")).thenReturn("Param1Value");
    when(request.getParameter("parameter2")).thenReturn("Param2Value");
    sut = new YourServletClass();
}


@Test
public void testMyServlet() throws Exception {
    sut.doPost(request, response);
    verify( /*....*/ );
}
```