# Eclipse, maven, tapestry, tomcat auto load

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat7, tapestry

I'm running eclipse mars EE. I have a maven project with tapestry 5.4.1. I have tomcat 7 maven plugin and everything is working fine except I'm not able to immediately see changes to tml and css files. When I make a change to any file it's eventually reloaded but it takes time which slows development. I want to be able to see css and tml changes instantly. I can wait for java changes until tomcat reloads them but I can't wait for css and tml changes.

I've read several articles on configuring the tomcat server within eclipse including this [stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998737/integrating-tomcat-and-eclipse-as-a-hot-deploy-environment)

However, they don't seem to work or achieve what I want. It seems the issue lies in the fact that tomcat has to wait for a new jar/war to be created and deployed instead of pulling the files directly from the project.

Also, I'm aware of Tapestry's [class reloading feature](https://tapestry.apache.org/class-reloading.html)....which doesn't seem to work either. Perhaps my project isn't configured correctly? Here is a [screen shot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TICGS.jpg)

There MUST be a way to accomplish this. We've all been writing web apps for tomcat in eclipse for 15 years!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have several issues that are described in the "Troubleshooting Live Class Reloading" section at the bottom of the https://tapestry.apache.org/class-reloading.html page. Please read the Tomcat-specific help at http://www.tynamo.org/Developing+with+Tomcat+and+Eclipse/ if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I re-read the tapestry class reloading page and..bingo! I automatically assumed that tapestry would not default to production mode but it appears that it does. I set configuration.add(SymbolConstants.PRODUCTION_MODE, "false") in my AppModule and that immediately corrected the problem.