# Tomcat can't recognize changes in Servlets

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

The problem is I started working on a project in Java EE Eclipse and its been a while I didn't open that project.

Now, when I try to add new Servlets or modify the old ones, it seems like I don't do any changes.

For example when I change the name of a servlet the browser still display the old one also when I change the text on a servelt it still display the old text.

Comment: delete the containers from the server and redeploy?

Comment: See the https://stackoverflow.com/a/999257/2935802