# tomcat server on Eclipse : how to make tomcat server reload project context at will

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat

I am writing a simple restful APT on Eclipse neon 3 and tomcat 7 (tomcat 9 does not work either). But Tomcat server could not update after I save my java code and run my project on the server. I noticed that only when the server reload the context like below, it executed the updated version of java files:

```
Sep 04, 2017 8:20:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/messenger] has started
Sep 04, 2017 8:20:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 04, 2017 8:20:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/messenger] is completed
```

The problem is how to make tomcat server reload project context at will so that I can reload the context whenever I want.

I have tried the following options, but all failed:

1) build project + run on sever

2) restart server

3) restart server on debug mood.

Also, tomcat server.xml reloadable property in Context is true be default.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998737/integrating-tomcat-and-eclipse-as-a-hot-deploy-environment and https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-reload

Answer (score 0):

Check your eclipse properties. Go to your project properties --> check deployment assembly and java build path.